# MS Access - Pass Through query best practice solution

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, pass-through

So I have a particular situation here with the CRM I'm tasked with developing, and I'd like to see if I can get some insight on more of a sanctioned, best-practice approach for this specific scenario. Basically, I have a form called **Accounts** that displays information specific to that account as well as a subform that needs to display quotes and orders associated with that account to give the user a snapshot of work done.

Due to the complexity of the query and number of possible records, scrolling through this subform can be slow if using a SQL VIEW or more obviously, a local access query. The best solution here is a pass through query so I can shoot that processing straight to SQL.

I've done quite a bit of research and the best approach I've seen is to either 1) use VBA to change the definition of the pass through query or 2) use an INSERT INTO statement to populate a local table which can be used as the recordsource for that subform. At this point I just want to confirm that either or both of these approaches would qualify as a best practice situation and possibly an example of code to make this happen. Right now I'm struggling with where this processing belongs. I don't want to call the code from the subform that launches the main **Accounts** form since this form can be opened from a few different places and I don't want to duplicate that code.

Here is the code I'm using to copy the dataset from the pass through query to a local table and then using the Master/Child relationship fields to only show the appropriate data for that account.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

'Purge local table where pass through results are copied
strSQL = "Delete * FROM tblPassThruResults"
db.Execute strSQL

'Insert the results of the pass through query into local table
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblPassThruResults Select Q_ACCOUNT_BUSINESS_OVERVIEW_PT.* FROM Q_ACCOUNT_BUSINESS_OVERVIEW_PT"
db.Execute strSQL

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: If the user selects the account they want to work with on the form, then using that input to constrain results from your passthrough seems like a really good idea to me.  You wouldn't need to get all the results from `Q_ACCOUNT_BUSINESS_OVERVIEW_PT`.

Comment: @bf2020 Right on. One of my thoughts and attempts has been to dynamically alter the SQL of `Q_ACCOUNT_BUSINESS_OVERVIEW_PT` so that it's only returning records for the selected account. I did run into some trouble getting that pass through query updated before the subform loaded and that's been my other struggle. Is this what you're getting at? Thanks!